# Remove class active onclick (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twig

I have an `ul` with up to 3 possible `li`'s inside (meaning it can have 1, 2 or 3). All 3, when clicked, open a modal and get an `class="active"`.

My goal is to remove that class when you close the modal using the `X` button on the top right corner.

This is the the portion of code inside the `ul` :

```
    {% for key, data in resources %}
        <li{% if loop.first %} ng-class="class" {% verbatim %}{{class}}{% endverbatim %} {% endif %} id="icon-resource">
            <a
                data-toggle="tab"
                href="#{{ key }}"
                segment-event="Modules: Tutor: Clicked {{ key|capitalize }} Section"
                segment-not-track-if-class="active"
                onclick="openAssistance()"
                ng-click="changeClass()"
            >
                <i class="icon-{{ key }} icon-sm"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">{{ ('resources.tabs.' ~ key ~ '.title') | trans }}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is the `X` button:

```
  <button type="button" class="close" toggle-class="oc-open" onclick="closeAssistance()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

This is the js I made to close the modal and remove the `active` class:

```
function openAssistance() {
  var x = document.getElementById('assistance');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function closeAssistance() {
  var x = document.getElementById('assistance');
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("icon-resource").classList.remove('active');
}
```

The problem is: it only removes the `active` class of the first icon, meaning that if you close the modal with the second or third icon active, it stays active.

I was hoping for an `angularjs` solution rather than a pure `js` like mine, but I'll be happy with either options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `getElementById` use `querySelectorAll` like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#icon-resource").forEach(function (li) {
    li.classList.remove("active");
});
```

But I suggest you to use a `class` instead of an `ID` because, at least in theory, `ID`s should be unique.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!
Care to explain the difference?

Comment: `getElementById` takes only the first occurrence from top to bottom of the `document` and returns the node, instead `querySelectorAll` returns an array with all nodes that matches with selector.

Comment: Oww I see! Thank you so much